# Converting string feature values on a dataset to numeric values in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, dataset

I have a dataset like

```
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
```

and I want to convert string values on that dataset to integer values like

```
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,0
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,0
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,0
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,0
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,1
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,1
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,1
```

so Iris-versicolor becomes 0 and Iris-versicolor becomes 1

How could I do it in Matlab nay practical suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in a cell array, i.e.

```
data = {...
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,'Iris-versicolor'
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,'Iris-versicolor'
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,'Iris-versicolor'
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,'Iris-versicolor'
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,'Iris-virginica'
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,'Iris-virginica'
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,'Iris-virginica'};
```

you can create your desired output as follows (subtract 1 from the output of `grp2idx`, since it starts counting at 1 (which is a practice you may want to adopt when using Matlab)):

```
[cell2mat(data(:,1:end-1)),grp2idx(data(:,end))-1]

    5.7000    2.9000    4.2000    1.3000         0
    6.2000    2.9000    4.3000    1.3000         0
    5.1000    2.5000    3.0000    1.1000         0
    5.7000    2.8000    4.1000    1.3000         0
    6.3000    3.3000    6.0000    2.5000    1.0000
    5.8000    2.7000    5.1000    1.9000    1.0000
    7.1000    3.0000    5.9000    2.1000    1.0000
```

Comment: my data is not cell array, it is plain txt fil and when I read it with textscan(fid,"%d %d %d %d %s","Delimiter",",") it gives a square character for each value. I guess it is not reading properly for some reason.

Comment: @Erogol: Put the comma between the format string, i.e. `%d,%d,` etc